# Not able anymore to create graph in Excel

Tags: excel, macos, office365

I am using Office365 for businesses (16.35) and Mac OS 10.14.6. I have for two weeks now (I suppose since the last office update) the problem that I am not able anymore to create graphs in Excel. However this problem goes further as I cannot open other documents as word or ppt with graphs. Excel will tell me that the document is damaged and will remove all graphs. I can do however everything else. If I take e.g. the Excel take a tour option, it crashes. 
Picture 2 shows it: It just says that we have a problem with some data and it has to be repaired.

If I open just a new file and try to create a very simple table as seen in the picture, and I then try to click on the graph icons nothing happens.

I tried to reinstall Office365 now twice, it did not help. 
As I did not find a similar problem description and really need Office365 to work from home, can anyone please be so kind and help me? Thank you!

[image: Trying to create a graph][image: Picture of the excel tour crash]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have solved the problem per se. However, it seems to be an issue with Mac OS. I can create a completely new user on Mac OS and Excel will run without a problem again. However, I was not able to solve the problem on my main account yet.